# Changing freq of triangle waveform verilog

Tags: verilog, waveform

So I've already got my triangle waveforms, now i want to change the frequency of it, but i'm getting errors and i don't know what's the actual problem.

```
module sxoc(clk,res,out1,freq,count);
input  clk,res;
input [0:7]freq;
output [0:7]count;
output [0:7]out1;
reg [0:7]out1;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (res)
    begin
        out1=8'b00000000;
        count=8'b00000000;
    end
    else
        count =count + 1;
        if (count == freq)
            if(out1<=256)
            begin
                out1=out1 + 1;
                count = 0;
            end
end
endmodule
module atam_test;
reg clk,res;
reg [0:7]freq;
wire [0:7]count;
wire [0:7]out1;
sxoc sxoc1(clk,res,out1,freq,count);
always #2 clk=~clk;
initial 
begin
clk=0;res=1;freq=8'b00000011;
#5 res=0;
end
initial #5000 $finish;
endmodule
```

[image: Compilation errors]

Comment: If it was working what did you change to alter the frequency? Clock rate or increment by 2 to make it ramp faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedural assignments (in an `always` block) can only be made to a `reg`. Change:

```
output [0:7]count;
```

to:

```
output reg [0:7]count;
```